# Keras: "loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00" coming while training the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm making a model (from this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/karangadiya/fifa19) which guesses the "overall" of a player given some of his statistics. I've done the required data cleaning but the loss and accuracy is coming as "loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00." 
Below is my code for data cleaning:-

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")
data.dropna().replace(np.nan, 0)
data.columns = [x.lower() for x in data.columns]
data = data.select_dtypes(include="number").drop(columns = ["id", "unnamed: 0"], axis=1)

y = data["overall"]
X = data[["crossing", "headingaccuracy", "standingtackle", "gkreflexes"]]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state=45)

X_train = (X_train - np.max(X_train))/(np.max(X_train) - np.min(X_train))
y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype = 'float32')
```

And here's my model's code:-

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(4, input_shape=(4,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
])
model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

This was the output while model training:-

```
Epoch 1/5
427/427 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
427/427 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
427/427 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/5
427/427 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/5
427/427 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x13b16c6e280>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try `keras.layers.Dense(1)` without the `activation=tf.nn.relu`. And also as its regression, you probably should use `metrics=["mae"]` and not `accuracy`.

Comment: @M.Innat not working...